# How are applications automatically launched at boot if they are not registered as services

Tags: 16.04, autostart, startup-applications

I have downloaded and started jetbrain toolbox executable once and now every time I boot my Ubuntu, I can instantly see jetbrains indicator. I'm not saying it's a bad thing, I just want to figure out how it is happening since the toolbox hasn't been installed explicitly and it's not a systemd/upstart service based on the results of `initctl list` and `service –status-all`.

Dropbox behaves quite similarly. I can't find it registered with any of service systems.

The difference between the two is that while I can at least find Dropbox installed on my machine, jetbrains-toolbox is not even installed(`dpkg -l | grep jetbrains` gives nothing).

Their processes are spawned by upstart based on System Monitor.

What if I want to control their start on boot? How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desktop environment automatically launches an application once you log in if the application's `.desktop` file is in one of the Autostart directories (viz. `/etc/xdg/autostart/`, `~/.config/autostart/`).

I believe you'll find `jetbrains` in `~/.config/autostart/` (but there's big chance I'll be wrong).

If the attribute `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=` in a particular `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/` is set to `true` then the application starts at login. You may disable this by changing it to `false`.

The method above should *not* to be tried with the `.desktop` files of system applications in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`. Instead go to `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and change the `NoDisplay=true` line in the `.desktop` file of interest to `NoDisplay=false`. Then the application should appear in the list of *Startup Applications*. You can disable it from there.

See [this](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way a application can start without registering them self as service. It register themself as startup application.

1. Open terminal and fire the below command

   ```
   sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
   ```

   This will show all the startup application.
   Source: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications)
2. Go to dash > application > In the search bar type startup application. You can see all the programs which is configured to start with system boot.

**WARNING:** Make sure you don't disable any important system application that can cause instability.